# Calculate fluid speed in a conduit with obstacles

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I need some advices to start to solve some problems about fluid motion in a conduit.

The problem domain is shown below: a conduit with some obstacle of different geometric properties.

[image: Motion of a fluid in a conduit]

The fluid is a "real" and viscous, the viscosity is very high in relation to speed (low speed, very high viscosity). The fluid is in pressure and comes from the blue arrow, I need to know the "speed or amount" of fluid in each output (red arrows). I don't need a real-time simulation.

How can I approach this kind of problem?

Comment: I think that you can use a CFD software like openFOAM or Fluent. Have you checked those?

Comment: I'm checking openFOAM thanks. I'm trying to implement this in a my application.

Comment: Are you interested in programming your own solver?

Comment: Yes, but for now I miss an "entry point" to start to evalute a possible implementation. Can I simplify or reduce the problem?

Comment: I think you can invoke Bernoulli's equations on this problem.  I don't think there is an need for numerical simulation (unless I'm missing some additional information here).

Comment: You say low speed and high viscosity, but what's the Reynolds number based on channel length and inflow velocity?

Comment: I have no idea of Reynolds number, but i think the fluid is in laminar flow. The fluid is a compound of clay.

Comment: $Re=\rho L U/\mu$, which you ought to be able to compute. You can find charts of laminar to turbulent transition for some objects like cylinders in terms of $Re$ or for flat plates. It's probably not turbulent, but it might be worth knowing.

Comment: Ok, but the Reynolds number must be calculated for every object in my conduit? If yes, after I calculate this, how I can approach a solver algorithm that, with a specified fluid (p, u, <v>) and a specified object geometry (size, angle, position),  can calculate the velocity of fluid in output?

Comment: You could probably start with the Reynolds number based on channel length to get an idea of whether the flow is laminar or not. If it is, then you might be able to get away with a streamfunction base approach that doesn't require too much in the way of a "solver" in 2 dimensions.

Comment: The fluid is very like the plastiline, I haven't at the moment sufficient data to calculate Re. The fluid is very viscous and it is extruded through a die (the obstacles in my picture).

Comment: If you're going to do any sort of simulation of this fluid, you're going to need to know the boundary conditions and material properties. Might as well get those in order.